# can't access mongodb - express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database

i can't access mongodb connection from express.js , here my rout and my error , i use Wndows OS
i can't access mongodb connection from express.js , here my rout and my error , i use Wndows OS
i can't access mongodb connection from express.js , here my rout and my error , i use Wndows OS

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var app = express();
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());



mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/user')



var userSchema = {
    _id : "string",
    name: "string",
    age : "number"
}


var user = mongoose.model('registration',userSchema,'user')


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {



   title: 'Home' 



    });
});




module.exports = router;
```

eror : http://s017.radikal.ru/i428/1502/d1/1581d782ccaa.png

Comment: let me see you folder structure

Comment: http://prntscr.com/64jvpk

Comment: What is 'www' script in bin? What happen when you run app.js?

Comment: stop posting scammy links to shady picture hosters. Why can't you simply copy & paste the error message?